# $Tim = time() - 60000; if($tit->Time >= $Tim){ echo"t: "; }

Tags: php

I want it to echo NEW beside a thread title if it was made less then or hour ago.
Once it's been an hour i want it to echo nothing.

This has worked before but will not work now, anyone know why this is not doing what i said above?

```
$Tim = time() - 3600;
if($tit->Time >= $Tim){
echo"NEW ";
}
```

Comment: Title says `60000` and the code is `3600`.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as it's not clear and is unlikely to be of benefit to anyone else in the future

Comment: This will benefit plenty of people.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $tit->Time >= strtotime('-1hour') ? 'New' : '';
```

Ensure, that `Time` is *really* a UNIX-timestamp. If it's not, you have to convert it first.

You can try

```
strtotime($tit->Time);
```

But that highly depends on what `$tit->Time` is

Comment: The Time is the database is a timestamp.

Comment: @Cody A "timestamp" is a point in the time in the first place. From the database' pov it can come in many forms, which is not necessarily a UNIX-timestamp (seconds sind 1970-01-01 00:00:00). Have a look at the content of the property `Time`